# Birthday problem, I'm confused by this formula

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I've given the following statement (n is given, and equals 100) :

[image: caption]

Now, I'm quite confused by the second binomial coefficient: how can that represent the days for the birthdays of the remaining 98 people? 364 choose 98 is a number close to a googol! It's $5*10^{90}$!!

Comment: How many $98$ letter strings are possible using $364$ different letters ?

Comment: $5\cdot 10^{90}$ may be large, but how do you think it compares to $365^{100}$?

Comment: Yep. $364$ options for the first person, $363$ options for the second person, $362$ options for the third person... $266$ options for the $98$th person. This finalizes to $\frac{363!}{265!}$, or $\binom{363}{265}\cdot98!$.

Comment: uh now I see ... yeah, it was a stupid question. I should have spent more time on it.